# Dimension of filtered algebras and their associated graded algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, clifford-algebras, graded-rings

Let $F$ be a finite dimensional filtered algebra and let $G$ be the associated graded algebra. Will the dimension of $G$ and $F$ coincide or differ in general? If they differ in general then what is the simplest example where they differ. For example - in the Clifford algebra case the filtered and graded algebra have the same dimension.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What about $\mathbb Q[T]$ vs $\mathbb Q[[T]]$ with $T$-adic filtration?

Comment: @Yai: ah, thanks, the argument I had in mind just doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\newcommand\K{\mathbb K}
$

Let $\{F_i\}$ be the filtration on $F$ and $\{G_i\}$ the grading on $G$, where by definition $G_0 = F_0$ and $G_{i+1} = F_{i+1}/F_i$. Then we can define a filtration $\{G'_i\}$ on $G$ by
$$
  G'_i = \bigoplus_{j=0}^i G_j
$$
and then
$$\begin{aligned}
  \dim G'_i
    &= \dim F_0 + \sum_{j=1}^i\dim F_j/F_{j-1}
\\
    &= \dim F_0 + \sum_{j=1}^i(\dim F_j - \dim F_{j-1})
\\
    &= \dim F_0 + \dim F_i - \dim F_0
\\
    &= \dim F_i.
\end{aligned}$$
Since $F$ is finite dimensional, each $F_i$ is a subspace, $F_i \subseteq F_{i+1}$, and $F = \bigcup_i F_i$, there must be some $k$ such that $F = F_k$. Thus $G = G'_k$ and $\dim F = \dim G$.

Comment: Note that there isn't necessarily a canonical isomorphism between $F$ and $G$ since all we did is count dimensions; in fact, in the case of Clifford algebras in characteristic 2 there is no canonical isomorphism.

Comment: I believe it wouldn't be too hard to extend this argument to infinite-dimensional spaces as well.

Comment: Did you mean to write in characteristic $\neq 2$?

Comment: @TheTralfamadorian No, as written my comment is correct.